# How to track Google Translator in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-translate

How can I track Google Translator which is installed on my website to track how many people translate from Spanish to English through Google Analytics or any other way? I already have Google Analytics setup for the site.

Answer (score 1):

During the setup process for Google Translator it should have asked you if you wanted to track translations inside of Google Analytics. From here give it a few days as you need to wait until users actually start translating your site then go to Google Analytics > Behavior > Events to find the Google Analytics translation events shown.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question, but they may be asking about users that use Google Translate from Google rather than from a site integration.

Comment: They do specifically mention translator as being installed on their website.